# Form is not inserting the value in the database by codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, validation

I am trying to insert values to the database by php codeigniter and display the result in the same page during submit. Here is my code,problem is i will not get any error message and do not insert the values to the database. Please help.
View Page

```
<div class="container col-lg-4">
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('Welcome/gallery1'); ?> 
<div class="form-group has-info">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
<br>
<label class="control-label col-lg-6" for="inputSuccess">Offer title
</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-6" name="offered" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['offered'])) echo $_POST['offered'];  ?>" id="offered">
<label class="control-label col-lg-6" for="inputSuccess">Offer Description
</label>
<textarea id="description" name="description" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['description'])) echo $_POST['description'];  ?>" class="form-control col-lg-6"  rows="3" >
</textarea>
<br/>
<div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-4">
<span>SUBMIT
</span>
</button>  
</div>  </div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

Controller page

```
public function gallery1()
{    
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('offered', 'required'); 
$this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'required');
$page_id =$this->uri->segment(3);
$this->load->model('Login_set');  
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
$data['h']=$this->Login_set->select(); 
$this->load->view('App_stay/pages/hotel1_galery.php',$data);
}
else 
{
$this->Login_set->save($data);           
}
}
```

Model page

```
public function add_offer() 
{
$this->load->database();
$this->load->helper('url');
$hotel_id=1;
$id = $this->input->post('id');
$offered = $this->input->post('offered');
$description = $this->input->post('description');       
$data = array('offers_name' => $this->input->post('offered'),
'offers_description' => $this->input->post('description')
);
return $this->db->insert('offer_hotel1',$data,array('hotel_id'=>$hotel_id));
}
```

Comment: why you pass third parameter in insert query?

Answer (score 0):

in your code it shows that if the validation true

```
$this->Login_set->save($data);
```

but in your model there is no save method, so you need to change **this**

```
$this->Login_set->save($data);
```

**TO**

```
$this->Login_set->add_offer();
```

**UPDATE**

There is no third parameter in insert() [SEE THIS](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)